# C/C++ Multiple Condition If Statement

Tags: c++, c

The program goes like this

```
if(z = x < y){
    x +=3;
    y -= 1;
}
else
    x = y++;
```

The input values are `x = 7` , `y = 7` and `z = 2`.
The output values are `x = 7` , `y = 8` and `z = 0`.

I am not sure how this statement works...
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: specially the if statement... i am not sure what the condition is

Comment: Compile and run the code. Add lots of logging until you do understand it. (Do you know yet which half of the `if` executes?)

Comment: i think the else part?

Comment: Why do you have an assignment and comparison in one line i.e. `if(z= x < y){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the comparison is evaluated, since `<` has higher priority than `=`. The result of the comparison is `false` (i.e. casted to 0), then `z` is made 0. The condition is then evaluated to `false`, so the `else` branch is executed, in which first the assignment is made, then `y` is incremented (see how postfix `++` operator works). BTW, you should never write code like this, but as `z = (x<y)`, so no one gets confused. The rest then follows.

Comment: I understand this is bad coding but it was just one of my test question that I never understood what it does

Answer (score 2):

Since `x < y` is false, you can mentally replace `x < y` with `false` in the `if`. That should make the code trivial to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The value of an assignment expression is the assigned value, so the value of `z = x < y` is just the value of `x < y` (i.e. either true or false). The variable `z` isn't used by your code, which could simply be written as:

```
if (x < y) { x += 3; y -= 1; }
else       { x = y; ++y;     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it graphically:

```
x = 7 ; y = 7 ;

if(z= x < y){  // x = (7 < 7)  => z = 0, 
  x +=3;   // Not executed
  y -= 1;
}
else   
 x = y++; // x = 7,   y = y + 1 (Y = 8)
```